# Sharing a file between two processes in Python. One process writes into it, another reads information and processes it. The process that reads is slow

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, flock

I am trying to communicate between two processes.
process 1 : collects artifacts links that I have to download by querying a database every 15 mins.
process 2 : should take these links and then download each of them in some specific folder. However, to download the artifacts, it takes a lot of time so the process 1 might be collecting a lot of links per hour and this may download only few.

How should I share the information between these two processes?
Until now , only thing I can think of is to maintain a file and lock it using fcntl.flock. The process 2(downloading process) can take each link and download it and repeat the process.

Do you have any better solutions ? please let me know!

Comment: Do you need the file's data later? If not, you might consider using a named pipe; the limited buffer size means process 1 can't run *wildly* ahead of process 2, and if the data is line oriented, process 2 can just iterate by line, and both sides will block automatically (process 1 when the pipe fills, process 2 when the pipe is empty).

Comment: OOC, is there some reason they need to be separate processes? A simple DB query is pretty trivial, why not integrate it into the downloader process?

Comment: @ShadowRanger , you mean multithread the process 1 and downloader process? I need the process 1 to run every 15 minutes 24/7 collecting data. Is it still possible to multithread it? Sorry, I am pretty new to python and multithread/process concepts.

Comment: Without details, it might or might not require threads (e.g. `asyncio` might work just fine, or just plain serial loops where it performs downloads until 15 minutes have passed, then polls the DB, then resumes downloads). There's a lot of options, but synchronizing file data between processes is a surprisingly hard problem (one databases exist to solve, among other issues), and it's highly likely you'd have an easier time sharing the data within the process, no matter what approach you take.